# Who was Rabi Tanchuma?

Tags: midrash, historical-figures

Was there an actual person Rabi Tanchuma attributed to writing the medrash that goes by this name? Do know anything about him?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanchuma

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @Double ^^^^^^^ continuing our conversation from the other day. Please let me know that you are aware of this as a Mod.

Answer (score 3):

See this other  [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanhuma_bar_Abba) that states:

> Tanhuma bar Abba (Hebrew: תנחומא בר אבא) was a Jewish amora of the 5th
>   generation, one of the foremost haggadists of his time. He was a pupil
>   of Ḥuna bar Abin (Num. R. iii.; Gen. R. xli.), from whom he transmits
>   halakic (Yer. Ḥal. 57d; Shab. 10c) as well as haggadic sayings (Yer.
>   Pe'ah 15b; Shab. 11d; Ab. Zarah 43a). He received instruction also
>   from Judah ben Shalom (Midr. Teh. to Ps. cxix. 2) and R. Phinehas
>   (Yer. Sheḳ. 49d). According to W. Bacher, he resided in Nave, a town
>   in Peræa (comp. A. Neubauer, G. T. p. 23).

Midrash Tanhuma was named after him because he was the first person named in that Midrash, but, the Midrash itself was written during the course of many years. This is common, like Avot D'Rav Nattan which was named after him for a similar reason.

Comment: These wiki entries don't answer why we should assume the person mentioned in the medrash is the same person in the gemara. Or why to assume the entire work wasn't written entirely by him. Also the other entry from user7032 is based of information from encyclopedia judaica. I have have nothing against scholarly secular  research as long as it has moral integrity. I don't concider information from an overtly antireligious work especially believable.

Comment: @user6591 - I generally take wikipedia entries loosely. However, part of the question asks more generally about Rabbi Tanhuma, and it makes reference to the Gemarrah that he was an Aggadist, which does collude with what the Gemarrah reference mentions. Granted, it doesn't completely or thoroughly answer the question, but it does cover what we know about Rabbi Tanhuma, in general - again a part of the OPs question.